# Mixing 2 audio files and return as 1 using PHP

Tags: php, web-applications, audio

I am developing a web application using Symfony 1.4. My requirement is that the user will upload an audio file, the web application should mix the uploaded file with the audio file already saved on the server, to output an entirely new file and save it on the server. Can it be done using PHP? For example, an audio file that resides on the server (containing vocals) needs to be mixed by a user uploaded audio file (containing drum beats) should output an audio(that plays the vocal with the drumbeats)

I have browsed a few questions at SO but couldn't really get a proper solution. I did come across SOX for mixing files from command line. But I don't think it will fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [webpage](http://www.theblog.ca/merge-mp3s-php) provides a very good code for doing just this.